# Query XMLELEMENT result is oracle/xdb/XMLType

Tags: xml, oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to create a XML from a table (and insert XML stuff into this table, but I'll do it step by step ...) and after some googling I found this:
http://allthingsoracle.com/generating-xml-from-sql-and-pl-sql-part-1/

So I tried the first part:

```
SELECT XMLElement( "NAME"
                 , NAME
                 )   FROM EMP;
```

But instead of getting something like this:

```
<NAME>bla</NAME>      
<NAME>muh</NAME>
```

I only get:

```
oracle/xdb/XMLType
```

as a result.
Is there anything I have to do before I can use the XMLElement?(I'm new to PL/SQL and this is pretty confusing)

I am using the SQL-Developer with the Version 4.1.2.20 on a Ubuntu 14.04 (I guess) machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "plain" Oracle JDBC driver (`ojdbc.jar`) does not support XML (neither the standard JDBC XML API, nor Oracle's internal XML API).

To enable the XML support you need to include the jar files `xdb6.jar` and `xmlparserv2.jar`.

[`xdb6.jar`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html) can be downloaded from the same page as the Oracle JDBC driver. `xmlparserv2.jar` seems to be only available as part of an Oracle server installation but I might be wrong there.

**Edit**:

It seems in SQL Developer all you need to do is to enable the display of XML:

[image]

---

Another option is to simply return the XML as a CLOB to the client:

```
SELECT XMLElement("NAME", NAME).getClobVal()
FROM emp;
```

That doesn't need any additional libraries

Comment: @ruudvan: no idea. As I said: I don't use SQL Developer. I just found that option after having a quick look.

Comment: Thanks, your second option worked(return as a CLOB). I don't have the time to test the rest toady, but I will try it out tomorrow.